# How to use multiple references to the same vueJs component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a php page `person.php` that includes 2 vueJs components: `person-details.vue` and `phones.vue`. Each of these components include the same third component `notify-delete`. This `notify-delete` component includes a bootstrap modal dialog to confirm a deletion action of the parent component (person or phone).
I use `props` to set a message in the modal confirmation dialog and `$refs` to show it.

**Problem**:
When this props is set the `msg` props from the component `person` and the dialog is shown, the message is correctly set. However when I set from the `phones` component, the dialog shows the message set by `person`. as if `person` is constantly overriding the value of the `msg` props.

here is a sample of the code:

**person.php**:

```
<person-details details="<?= json_encode($person) ?>"></person-details>
<phones details="<?= json_encode($phones) ?>"></phones>
```

**Person-details.vue**:

```
<template>
    <notify-delete ref="modalDeletePerson" :entity="'person'" :msg="deleteMsg" @confirmed="deleteMe"></notify-delete>
    <button type="button" @click="confirmDelete">Delete this person</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                deleteMsg: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            confirmDelete() {
                this.deleteMsg = 'Are you sure you want to delete this person?'
                this.$refs.modalDeletePerson.show()
            },
            deleteMe() {
                // delete person
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</template>
```

**Phones.vue**:

```
<template>
    <notify-delete ref="modalDeletePhone" :entity="'phone'" :msg="deleteMsg" @confirmed="deleteMe($event)"></notify-delete>

    <button type="button" @click="confirmDelete">Delete this phone</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                deleteMsg: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            confirmDelete() {
                this.deleteMsg = 'Are you sure you want to delete this phone?'
                this.$refs.modalDeletePhone.show()
            },
            deleteMe() {
                // delete phone
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Notify-delete.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div id="modalDelete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{msg}}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" @click="confirm">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['entity', 'msg'],

        methods: {
            show() {
                $('#modalDelete').modal('show')
            },

            confirm() {
                this.$emit('confirmed')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any idea how I can have two distinguish instances of the same component?

Comment: Do you have a typo in `Person-details.vue` in the template, as you have written it here?

Comment: Yes, there was an extra paste. Thank you. I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
show() {
    $('#modalDelete').modal('show')
}
```

You are rendering two modals with the same id, then using jQuery to show them. Specifically, `$('#modalDelete')` will contain two elements. I expect the `modal` method just picks the first one and shows it.

Try

```
<div ref="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

and

```
show() {
    $(this.$refs.modal).modal('show')
}
```

This should give each instance of the `Notify-delete.vue` component it's own reference.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!